# open bootstrap modal from modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to open a new bootstrap modal view from an actually opened modal view.

I'm using the following template to open all my different modals:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">&nbsp;</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="alert alert-error" style="text-align: center;">
      <strong>ERROR!</strong><br />You should not be able to see this text!^
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    $("a[data-target=#myModal]").click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr("href");

        // load the url and show modal on success
        $("#myModal .modal-body").load(target, function() {
            $("#myModal").modal("show");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then I call my modals with RoR:

```
<a href='<%= url_for :controller => :customers, :action => :new %>' data-target='#myModal' type='button' class='btn' role='button' data-toggle='modal'>
  <i class="icon-plus"></i> new Customer</a>
```

actually, when i press a button inside a modal like that one, nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the `data-toggle="modal"` attribute should not be used when you use your own modal loading, because the remote page will be loaded twice (by you and the plugin).

Secondly, when you bind events, it only uses the elements already on the page, unless you use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) like :

```js
$(document).on('click','a[data-target="#myModal"]', function(ev) {

});
```

Notice the simple quotes `'` around the selector and the double quotes `"` around the attribute value.

And from there, it should work : [Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/FH7md/)

Comment: I tried to include your code sample. now I've some problems more: 1. nothing is opening in a modal any more. I think the reason is, that I'm using RoR maybe? 2. After opening a modal and closing it again, I'm not able any more to open it without reloading the page.

Comment: @Adrian Try putting the JS in `$(function() { /* the code */ });` so that it waits for the [`onDomReady`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3), like [that fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/FH7md/5/). Check the JS errors. I'm guessing your binding never happens, or the `.load(target)` call might be failing. Check the network inspector of your browser.